# Removed Facetime - how to recover?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, facetime

So I got this weird situation probably because of my own stupidity. But here goes: I am on Lion (10.7.3) and decided to install FaceTime from the App Store. When trying to install the App Store app says that I need to move current FaceTime.app to trash. When trying to do so the OS says that I cannot remove FaceTime app since it's required by OS. Being confused I open the terminal and go all `sudo rm -fr` on FaceTime.app. Getting back to App Store I try to install the FaceTime again, but this time I get message saying that MAS version of FaceTime is too old for my OS.

So basically my question boils down to - how do I get my FaceTime app back?

Comment: **Mac Rule of Thumb**if *sudo* is required, you're (in all likelihood) *doing it wrong*, particularly for installing an Apple provided software package. At the very least, it should trigger your *Spidey sense* and a thorough examination of the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the FaceTime.app file from your backup or another machine with the same OS version should work.

Comment: My first response would be *recover the app from your own backup.* If you don't have a backup, or access to another copy, you can reinstall Lion which doesn't overwrite your user account. (You *might* also be able to locate and recover the app within a copy of the install image, but I haven't explored that fully.)

Comment: Don't reinstall for just a single file! If anything, you can just ask kindly for some one here to upload the file for you

Answer (score 2):

**FaceTime** is part of the Mac OS since Lion. You should not have had to install this in the first place.

- The version of FaceTime in the Mac App Store is [1.0.2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facetime/id414307850?mt=12) and for Snow Leopard (since 10.6.6).
- The version of FaceTime in Lion is [1.1.1](http://d.pr/Gk20).

(as of march 2012)

This explains the warning "FaceTime is too old for my OS".

Try to copy the `FaceTime.app` package from another Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Presume your Trash doesn't have a copy?  There's not a lot you can do without having access to the Lion media.

You should be able to download the whole installer again (Go into the Mac App store, and `Option-Click` on Purchases tab to get the option back), extract the DMG from the installer package (Right click and `Show Package Contents`), and then hunt down the bits for Facetime.

I'm curious why you did what you did, but it's interesting that it let you get that far.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why I did what I did. The `rm -fr` doesn't move stuff to trash, so it's gone for good. Will need to check out the dmg thing.